# oraclize price for random value too high (rinkeby)?

Tags: oracles

Currently, when I call

```
oraclize_getPrice("random", 400000);
```

I get back

```
8000000000000000
```

on rinkeby. That'd be over 2$ USD if on the mainnet and also looks oddly round.
Why is this so high?

Answer (score 2):

Your `oraclize_getPrice("random", 400000)` returns 8000000000000000 because it calculates `gasLimit * gasPrice` with the given gasLimit of 400000 and the default gasPrice of 20 Gwei.
**The total cost is calculated by: `$0.05 +( call of your __callback() + execution gas of the __callback()) * gasPrice`** However, in practice it's calculated by `$0.05 + CUSTOM_GAS_LIMIT * CUSTOM_GAS_PRICE` whereby CUSTOM_GAS_LIMIT should be enough to execute your `__callback()` and CUSTOM_GAS_PRICE high enough to have the transaction be mined in time.

See below how to influence these values:

There are three factors affecting the "real" price of using oraclize:

1. The **gas cost of your `__callback()` function**. This function is called by Oraclize and must be paid by your contract.
2. (Closely related to (1)) The **gas limit** used by Oraclize to send the answer to your contract. By default, oraclize uses a gas limit of 200k when calling your `__callback()`. These 200k are paid by your contract. However, **unused gas will be returned to Oraclize - not to your contract!** Try and error to find a close value and use it in `oraclize_newRandomDSQuery(delay, N, CUSTOM_GASLIMIT)` and `oraclize_getPrice("random", CUSTOM_GASLIMIT)`.
   **This value MUST BE >= than the value determined in (1).**
3. The set **gas price**. By default, oraclize uses a relatively high price of 20Gwei. Currently, according to [Ethgasstation.info](https://ethgasstation.info/), 3-4 Gwei would be enough (this alone lowers your cost by 80%!). You can set it in your constructor or any other function by calling `oraclize_setCustomGasPrice(customGasPrice)`. I suggest not to hardcode that value because the requirements may vary in times of high network load. **If your gasPrice is too low, the oraclize callback to your contract may take very long or may even never be mined.**

Here's an example how I handle these values:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
import "oraclize-api/contracts/usingOraclize.sol";

contract MyContract is usingOraclize {

  // USD Cent value of 1 ether. Init with non-zero value.
  uint256 public ethusd = 1;

  // Sold out / sale active?
  bool public soldOut = false;  

  // Oracle active?
  bool public oracleActive = false;

  // Delay between autonomous oraclize requests
  uint256 public oracleInterval;

  // Gas price for oraclize callback transaction. 5 Gwei
  uint256 public oracleGasPrice = 5000000000;

  // Gas limit for oraclize callback transaction
  // Unused gas is returned to oraclize.
  uint256 public oracleGasLimit = 100000;


  constructor(uint _oracleInterval, uint _oracleGasPrice) public {
    require(_oracleInterval > 0);
    require(_oracleGasPrice > 0);

    oracleInterval = _oracleInterval;    
    oracleGasPrice = _oracleGasPrice;

    oraclize_setCustomGasPrice(_oracleGasPrice);
  }

  // Activate ethusd oracle and load contract with ETH
  function activateOracle() external payable {
    oracleActive = true;
    requestEthUsd(0);
  }

 /**
   * @dev Request ETHUSD rate from oraclize
   * @param _delay in seconds when the request should be scheduled from now on
   */
  function requestEthUsd(uint _delay) internal {
    if (oracleActive && !soldOut) {
      if (oraclize_getPrice("URL") > address(this).balance) {
        oracleActive = false;
      } else {
        if (_delay == 0) {
          oraclize_query("URL", "json(https://api.gdax.com/products/ETH-USD/ticker).price", oracleGasLimit);
        } else {
          oraclize_query(_delay, "URL", "json(https://api.gdax.com/products/ETH-USD/ticker).price", oracleGasLimit);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * @dev Called by oraclize.
   */
  function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) public {
    if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) revert();
    ethusd = parseInt(result, 2);
    requestEthUsd(oracleInterval);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Public function to set the oracle gas price.
   */
  function setOracleGasPrice(uint256 _gasPrice) external {
    require(_gasPrice > 0, "Gas price must be a positive number.");
    oraclize_setCustomGasPrice(_gasPrice);
    oracleGasPrice = _gasPrice;
  }


  /**
   * @dev Public function to set the oracle gas limit.
   */
  function setOracleGasLimit(uint256 _gasLimit) external {
    require(_gasLimit > 0, "Gas limit must be a positive number.");
    oracleGasLimit = _gasLimit;
  }


  /**
   * @dev Public function to set the oracle query interval.
   */
  function setOracleInterval(uint256 _interval) external {
    require(_interval > 0, "Interval must be > 0");
    oracleInterval = _interval;
  }
}
```

This way you're able to apply new values even after contract deployment. **The cost of my "URL" query has been lowered from $1.20 to $0.13**.

NB: you should make your contract ownable and limit access to some of the above functions to the contract owner.

Comment: Not sure I understand the difference between 1. & 2. - isn't the callback function gas cost exactly what I'm paying by specifying the oracleGasLimit?

Comment: Indeed, they're related. Point 1 is the "real" cost on the EVM. Point 2 is what you're willing to pay. P2 should always be > P1. In contrast to the gasLimit set in MetaMask transactions, you don't get unused gas back. This is important to understand.

Comment: I still don't get how such a high return value is possible. I pass in 400000 as gas limit to the query.Gas station reports for 400000 a price of 0.254 usd$ currently (that's on main net of course) and the pricing website of oraclize states a 0.05$ fee for the random service. So how is the returned value over 2 usd$?

Comment: The total cost is calculated by: `$0.254 +( call of your __callback() + execution gas of the __callback()) * gasPrice`. But since oraclize does not know how much gas is needed in total, you have to deliver a close value by your own.

Comment: I updated my answer for clarification.

Comment: haggis, why 0.254$ PLUS the execution price of the callback? the 0.254$ ARE the supposed cost of the callback (if entering the gaslimit specified into gasstation)

Comment: Because $0.254 is only the **base price** THEY charge. See https://docs.oraclize.it/#pricing for more information.

Comment: but their pricing table states 0.05$ baseprice, not 0.25$

Comment: Indeed, just took that value from your comment. Will correct it...